# Laravel 5.2 Custom Provider Not Found

Tags: laravel, package, provider

I'm using laravel 5.2 and try to create my own package, so i creating my package folder, and this is my dir:

```
root
-packages
--yudijohn
---composer.json
---crud-generator
----src
-----CrudGeneratorServiceProvider.php
```

this is the content of my composer.json, i make i with composer init

```
{
    "name": "yudijohn/crud-generator",
    "description": "Laravel 5 Crud Generator",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravelcollective/html": "5.1.*"
    },
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Yudi Yohanes Septian Gotama",
            "email": "yudijohn.sg@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "yudijohn\\CrudGenerator\\": "packages/yudijohn/crud-generator/src"
        }
    }
}
```

and add a provider setting at app/Provide.php

```
App\Providers\PackageServiceProvider::class,
yudijohn\CrudGenerator\CrudGeneratorServiceProvider::class,
```

and this is the content of my CrudGeneratorServiceProvide.php

```
namespace yudijohn\CrudGenerator;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class CrudGeneratorServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
        $this->commands(
            'yudijohn\CrudGenerator\Commands\CrudCommand',
            'yudijohn\CrudGenerator\Commands\CrudControllerCommand',
            'yudijohn\CrudGenerator\Commands\CrudModelCommand',
            'yudijohn\CrudGenerator\Commands\CrudMigrationCommand',
            'yudijohn\CrudGenerator\Commands\CrudViewCommand'
        );
    }
}
```

but when i try to php artisan serve, this error show up

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]                
Class 'yudijohn\CrudGenerator\CrudGeneratorServiceProvider' not found
```

i dont know why the class is not found? what must i do to solve this error?
please someone help me

this is PackageServiceProvider.php

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

use Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder;

use Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem;

class PackageServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
            $this->loadAutoloader(base_path('packages'));
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
        }

        /**
        * Require composer's autoload file the packages.
        *
        * @return void
        **/
        protected function loadAutoloader($path)
        {
            $finder = new Finder;
            $files = new Filesystem;

            $autoloads = $finder->in($path)->files()->name('autoload.php')->depth('<= 3')->followLinks();

        foreach ($autoloads as $file)
        {
            $files->requireOnce($file->getRealPath());
        }
        }

}
```

Comment: Did you make `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: yes i do, after create all that files i do composer dump-autoload at root, but it's still error

Comment: khm, very weird, try to add trailing slash to end of the path.

Comment: i add slash at the path on composer, it's still get not found error, what happen with this? this is the error detail PHP Fatal error:  Class 'yudijohn\CrudGenerator\CrudGeneratorServiceProvider' not found in /home/yudi/Documents/dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php on line 146

Comment: @xAoc i add my PackageServiceProvider.php content, maybe i wrong here

Comment: and you already added your service provider in app.php providers?

Comment: @xAoc yes 

        App\Providers\PackageServiceProvider::class,
        
        /*
        * Package Service Providers
        */
        yudijohn\CrudGenerator\CrudGeneratorServiceProvider::class,

Comment: @xAoc but i dont have any autoload.php at packages folder

Comment: I don't understand what your `PackageServiceProvider` doing, why you create it?

Comment: i'm following this tutorial https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/tips/developing-your-packages-in-laravel-5 if you have other good tutorial please i need it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to add 
`"yudijohn\\CrudGenerator\\": "packages/yudijohn/crud-generator/src"`
to the `composer.json` at your **project** root, not the package you just made. It should go right below the `"App\\": "app/"` entry.

After that, run `composer dump-autoload` to add it to composer's autoloaded classes.

I also don't believe you need `PackageServiceProvider.php`, it seems redundant to add another autoloader when you're using composer.

Also make sure your filename and classnames are the same, you mentioned `CrudGeneratorServiceProvide.php` while your class name is `CrudGeneratorServiceProvider` (notice the r at the end of the classname)

Here's a good resource for further research: https://github.com/jaiwalker/setup-laravel5-package

Comment: thanks bro, my problem is add to composer.son at my project root not at my package!